# Отправка файла с сайта на почту HTML JS PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Всем привет, помогите, пожалуйста, нашел статью, как сделать форму с полями и прикреплением файла, сделал все по инструкции, но письма не отправляются.
Была задача: Сделать форму с именем телефоном и возможностью прикрепить файлы, дальше чтобы эти данные отправлялись с сайта на почту админа сайта. Снизу приложил код что получилось. Прошу помочь. Заранее спасибо

```js
$(function(){
 ‘use strict’;
$(‘#form’).on(‘submit’, function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var fd = new FormData( this );
 $.ajax({
 url: ‘send.php’,
 type: ‘POST’,
 contentType: false, 
 processData: false, 
 data: fd,
 success: function(msg){
if(msg == ‘ok’) {
 $(“.button”).val(“Отправлено”); 
} else {
 $(“.button”).val(“Ошибка”);
 setTimeout(function() {$(“.button”).val(“Отправить”);}, 3000);
}
 }
 });
 });
});
```

```html
<form action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
            <h1>Запись на консультацию</h1>
            <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Введите Ваше имя">
            <input name=”number” type=”text” required placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон">
            <input placeholder=”example@mail.com” name=”email” type=”text” required>
            <label for="fileFF">Загрузите файл</label>
            <input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple id="userfile" required>
            <br>
            <input value="Отправить" type="submit" name="submit">
            <a href="#" class="close">Закрыть</a>
          </form>
```

И PHP

```
<?php                                                                      
// Файлы phpmailer
require ‘phpmailer.php’;
require ‘smtp.php’;
// Переменные
$name = $_POST[‘name’];
$number = $_POST[‘number’];
$email = $_POST[‘email’];
// Настройки
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = ‘smtp.yandex.ru’; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = ‘rumyantsev.pavel2017; // Ваш логин в Яндексе. Именно логин, без @yandex.ru
$mail->Password = ‘GFIFGFIF2002’; // Ваш пароль
$mail->SMTPSecure = ‘ssl’; 
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->setFrom(‘rumyantsev.pavel2017@yandex.ru’); // Ваш Email
$mail->addAddress(‘rumyantsev.pavel2017@yandex.ru’’); // Email получателя
$mail->addAddress(‘rumyantsev.pavel2017@yandex.ru’’); // Еще один email, если нужно.
// Прикрепление файлов
 for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES[‘userfile’][‘tmp_name’]); $ct++) {
 $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES[‘userfile’][‘name’]    [$ct]));
 $filename = $_FILES[‘userfile’][‘name’][$ct];
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[‘userfile’][‘tmp_name’][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
 $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
 } else {
 $msg .= ‘Failed to move file to ‘ . $uploadfile;
 }
 } 

// Письмо
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = “Заголовок”; // Заголовок письма
$mail->Body = “Имя $name . Телефон $number . Почта $email”; // Текст письма
// Результат
if(!$mail->send()) {
 echo ‘Message could not be sent.’;
 echo ‘Mailer Error: ‘ . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
 echo ‘ok’;
}
?>
```

Comment: Если честно то меня больше всего смущают кавычки, возможно вы скопировали с неправильными кавычками поменяйте на ' и " соответственно

Comment: Возможно вы тестируете с локального сервера и майлер не пропускает письма а ложит их в папку email а возможно вы не правильно подключаете библиотеки и пути не относительны файлам

Comment: я нашел видео (другое), полностью скопировал файлы и залил на хост, только изменил почту и пароль, но выдает ошибку, может поможете мне в ЛС, пожалуйста?

Comment: Вы сейчас сюда вставили код из файлов с которых пытаетесь отправить?

Comment: Если да то `‘` и `’` поменяйте на `'` а `“` и  `”` на `"`

Comment: `yandex.ru’’` вообще дикость

Comment: у меня уже другой код

Comment: я же говорю посмотрел видео у опытного человека, у него все работает. Я полностью скопировал файлы его (была ссылка в описании) залил на хостинг, изменив mail и все равно не работает

Comment: Дык покажите этот другой код! именно тот что вы используете для отправки! Если выше он то у вас кавычки с ошибкой их не обрабатывает интерпретатор

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80093/discussion-between---and-walfter).

Answer (score 0):

Проверенное оттестированное решение

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'src/Exception.php';
    require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'src/SMTP.php';
    require 'language/phpmailer.lang-ru.php';

    $msg = '';
    if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.server.ru';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'login@server.ru';
        $mail->Password = 'uPassword';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Port = 465;

        $mail->setFrom('login@server.ru', 'PHP Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress($_POST['to'], '');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
        $mail->msgHTML('My message body');        

        $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4"); 

        for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
            $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
            $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.'), strlen($filename) - 1); // В переменную $ext заносим расширение загруженного файла.
            if (in_array($ext, $blacklist)) {die();}

            $uploadfile = dirname(__FILE__)."/uploads/" . basename($filename);
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
                $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, basename($filename));
            } else {
                $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
            }
        }
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $msg .= "Message sent!";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PHPMailer Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (empty($msg)) { ?>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="to" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760">
        Select one or more files:
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple="multiple">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Files">
    </form>
<?php } else {
    echo $msg;
} ?>
</body>
</html>
```